# Circuit changing the color of an led with a button?

Tags: led, transistors, circuit-design, button

I'm trying to make a circuit WITHOUT the use of any IC's or micro controllers. I'm basing it so far off of the circuit in the picture. Im planning on adding a flip flop circuit to it to make it the light stay on when you touch it.

The issue I'm having though is that this circuit would only light the led in one color. I have a 4 pin led and my end goal is to have the circuit able to switch between each color every time you touch the "button".

Ive been stumped on this for days. There has to be a way to wire this up manually so I don't have to use an IC or a micro controller right?
 [image]

Comment: You're going to have a hard time doing this without some sort of counter (or Johnson counter) IC. Of course you're stumped.

Comment: But it's possible right? The reason I don't want to use IC's is because I plan to make a lot of these circuits and connect them together.

Comment: Look up the SCS circuit (it's a latching circuit). Derive from there. If I can figure out myself I'll post an answer. And of course it's possible, it's just going to be complicated.

Comment: @kingduken yeah I got this circuit off a website. I plan to have a 4 pin led rather than a 2 pin

Comment: @Bradman175 alright thanks man will do! Appreciate any help!

Comment: The way you configured your circuit _will_ only give you one color because you have the button and the 9V battery directly on the terminals of the four pin LED. Also, since you mentioned a four terminal LED your schematic above it doesn't contain a four terminal LED, just two. Lastly, @Bradman175 suggested a counter because you need something that transitions between the different colors. (I couldn't edit my comment so I wrote a new comment, sorry).

Comment: @kingduken the picture was mainly just a reference point so people cold visualize the circuit. This is just the base I plan to use. I'm going to change and vary the components to get the intended goal. It's just I can't figure out how to incorporate more transisters, capacitors, or whatever it needs to be able to mechanically switch between each led lead. Just pretend there is a 4 pin led there. How could I wire this up to manually shift through each color, assuming all the wires are wired correctly?

Comment: Just use a micro. This is almost trivial for whatever little 8-bit 8-pin PIC, AVR, or anything else really. In the days you've spent getting nowhere you might have already been done.

Comment: What is it with so many beginners insisting on doing things without using ICs? Is it a hipster thing? Fear of having to solder SMT components?

Comment: @LukeyP For this 4pin LED you got, is it common anode or common cathode?

Comment: Do you realize that "4 pin LED" is ambiguous? There are 4-pin LEDs with two internal LEDs (both ends brought out) and with 3 (RGB, at least, with common anode or common cathode). There are also 4-pin LEDs with serial interface driver chips inside such as WS2811 and sometimes regulators. Post a link to to the datasheet or part number if your rep does not allow links.

Comment: @JeannePindar - I think it's the feeling that if something's easy, you're not doing it right.

Answer (score 3):

If you create the following circuit:
[image]
(Which came from [here](https://www.jaycar.com.au/medias/sys_master/hb9/h82/8884450394142/BJ8502-ShortCircuits-1-310316.pdf) page 39)

...and then try to use your touch switch circuit so that it pauses the chaser, you can achieve what you want. Of course this means if you touch the button long enough, you can cycle multiple colours, but view it as a feature! ;)

Answer (score 3):

Stepping through the three LEDs in sequence requires a ring counter, a form of circular shift register.  There are many ways to grow one from scratch, but none are as simple as a CD4017.

Comment: This is the obvious best solution for simplicity. route stage after last used back to reset to reduce cycle length for rotating colors. then driver current depends on LED and buffer may be needed.

Comment: 74HC4017 has about 150 ohms ESR @5V

Answer (score 2):

You say you don't want to add any ICs but then you say you are planning on adding a flip-flop, so I am not sure what you really mean by IC.  But since you are willing to consider a flip flop I have a suggestion.

If I were you I would consider designing a logic circuit from 4000B series CMOS logic.  They are cheap chips so you can buy lots of them for as many of these things as you are inclined to build.  It also has all the useful functions that you will need: flip-flops, counters, and all the other useful operators.  The other good thing about 4000B series is that it can take +15V (or more) power rails.  Designing from CMOS logic will give you a more robust and reliable circuit than trying to use only transistors and passives, (I promise.)

You will probably want to use the 4000B series CMOS to drive bjt's that switch the led because the output current drive of the logic isn't great.  This isn't a problem.

I think your control logic may get a little complicated at first pass, but it is a fun problem (at least I think so.)  It will give you an opportunity to get clever and get a working circuit!  Check out: CMOS Cookbook; Author ‑ DON LANCASTER for a good reference.  Good luck.